# What grit sandpaper should I use to remove polyurethane from hardwood floors?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I wanted to re-clear my hardwood floors in my home but I didn't know what grit sandpaper I needed to do so. What is the best sandpaper grit to use in removing the polyurethane coat on a hardwood floor?

Comment: Scuff-sand to recoat, or sanding down to bare wood?

Answer (score 2):

Start with a rougher grit sandpaper and work your way down to a smooth paper.  Generally I use three different papers.  Rough to remove the majority of the varnish, medium to get the rest of the finish and smooth any larger wood issues, then a third run with a fine paper to make it all smooth.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for removing the finish, I was told its more of a trial and error approach.  We had very old floors with a very thick finish on them.  So I was told to start with 36, if the sander did not go all the way to the wood or do a decent job removing the majority, then drop down to a 24 grit paper.